# SSH - Java JDBC connection - Hibernate connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, ssh

I have an oracle could db which installed in windows server.

To access db,

1. Create SSH tunnel to host machine.
2. On success SSH tunnel, establish local port forward to server machine to access db.

For SSH tunnel with local port forward, we using JSch (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

After that we using connection url as *jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:${LOCAL_PORT_FORWARD}/service_name* to connect db from both jdbc and hibernate.

> LOCAL_PORT_FORWARD - get local port at runtime(i.e after success SSH tunnel with local port forward)

Here the problem is if SSH tunnel disconnected,

1. What is the possible way to re-connect SSH with local port forward in Java
2. How to reconnect db from jdbc?
3. How to reconnect db from Hibernate? Session factory already injected to some beans while application start. So if reload session factory how to handle those beans?

Comment: Technically you are not really asking anything that is related to java, spring, hibernate, jdbc or Oracle. It isn't even really a programming question. It sounds more like a SSH configuration thing: you just need to ensure your SSH tunnel uses a fixed port, the rest of the reconnection thing would then be the same as for non-SSH cases.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the info. I try to use fixed port for SSH tunnel.